# Re-render component when using history.push() to the same component but a different url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I've got a stateful component that I'm using as a container/page component to fetch data from my database and render some information. The URL for this page is for example `myurl.com/admin/orders/order-2019-3`

On the page I've got a previous and next button. When pushing one of these, the user has to see the data of the previous or next order. To do this I'm using and onClick function with `this.props.history.push` and the url of the previous or next order. For example `this.props.history.push('/admin/orders/order-2019-4')`.

Unfortunately only the url is changing. The page isn't reloading and the data of order 2019-4 isn't fetching.

So my question: Do I have to force and update or is this approach wrong (Do I have to replace the URL and call a function that fetches the new data?)

Note: I'm using `react-router-v4`

Some code of my container component:

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const snapshot = await Database.ref(`orders/${this.props.match.params.orderID}`).once('value');

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const order = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({ order: snapshot.val() });
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/admin/orders');
    }

    this.setState({ isFetching: false });
}


render() {
    const { order } = this.state;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <header>
                <h1>{order.general.orderID}</h1>
            </header>

            <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/admin/orders/order-2019-03')}>Previous order</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for me to be really helpful. A couple things that would help me are: what is the relevant component code for this situation? If you put a console log in component did update for you order page, does it say anything?

Comment: @RyanDabler Updated the question and yes `componentDidUpdate` is being called when the `push` function/page url is called/changing

Comment: What is the code for `componentDidUpdate`? Since `render` is getting `order` from state, does `componentDidUpdate` get a new snapshot from your database?

Comment: No the data is only fetched in componentWillMount. Maybe my question wasn't clear. What's the correct approach? 

1) Do I have to force a complete re-render so componentWillMount can run again and fetch the data

2) Do I have to check for a change in the url and fetch new data in componentDidUpdate

3) Am I doing something wrong why it's not working with the code I have right now

Comment: I think that's your problem. If you don't refetch data when the URL changes you'll always have data out of data (i.e., only reflecting the order that was indicated by the URL when the component mounted). You'll want to add similar logic in `componentWillMount` to `componentDidUpdate` in order to fetch the new document. I don't recommend unmounting and remounting your component because you'll incure the overhead of rebuilding that component.